Android WebRTC - How to release mic control from Android Wear OS App?
We have used WebRTC to implement audio call features to Android Wear OS devices. When call is in progress if the user tries use the Google assistance or any voice recorder, other apps don't get access to mic,our app still control on the mic.
Please let me how to release mic from app when other apps tries use the mic?
